# convert CStdStringW to TCHAR *

Tags: c++, casting

I have a piece of code that originally used CString. Since it is not available to VSExpress users I replaced it with a CString "clone" found at:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/stdstring.aspx

This clone works just fine but one problem remains when using it:

```
TCHAR *GetConnectionString(){return m_szConnectionString)};
```

I get the error "no suitable conversion from "CStdStringW" to "TCHAR *" exists" and since string handling not really is my strength I don't know how to resolve this. Ok I know that I probably have to do some kind of type cast but....
The whole piece of code can be found at: 
[Use CString in console app when using VS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760186/use-cstring-in-console-app-when-using-vs-express)

Well, have a nice day and hopefully someone can help my with.

Regards Lumpi

Comment: you should use std::string os std::wstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you commit to a non-standard string class, you're stuck with having to use it.  You ought to change the return value type:

```
CStdString GetConnectionString() {
    return m_szConnectionString;
};
```

The other option is to change the return type from TCHAR to const TCHAR:

```
const TCHAR* GetConnectionString() {
    return (LPCTSTR)m_szConnectionString;
};
```

Which isn't a great solution, it will fail miserably when the calling code stores the pointer and the connection string is changed.  This is a flaw in the original code too btw.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I'll keep that issue in mind. Probably will learn it the hard way ( "it will fail miserably...") but I try to implement your advise right away.   Lumpi

Answer (score 1):

According to the link you posted, `CStdString` derives from [`basic_string<TCHAR>`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html). Thus, you can use its [c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) method.

```
const TCHAR *GetConnectionString()
{
    return m_szConnectionString.c_str();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Frédéric ! Now it compiles without errors! I really hate the fact that there exist about 5billion different types of strings and chars. Ok, i understand that some different basic versions are nedded, but to me it feels like I find a new "string issue" every day..  Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Lumpi, you think C++ has string issues? You should try plain C sometime, so you can see what *real* string issues are (hint: *no string type* ;)